# Sort matrix according to indices from matlab's sortrows in IronPython without using NumPy

Tags: python, matlab, sorting

### Problem

I'm trying to translate Matlab code to IronPython.

```matlab
[~, ind] = sortrows([phi, Z]);
K_sort = K(ind,ind);
```

[Result with Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZoVs.png)

It should sort matrix `K` according to indices from `sortrows` without using `NumPy` or other libraries that are not included in IronPython 2.7.0.

### What I have tried

```py
phi_uniq = sorted(list(set(phi)))
z_uniq = sorted(list(set(z)))

num_z = len(z_uniq)
num_phi = len(phi_uniq)

I = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(phi_r), key=lambda x:x[1])]
z_sort = [z_r[i] for i in I] 

ind_z = []
for j in range(num_z):
    ind_z.append([i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(z_sort[num_phi*j:num_phi*(j+1)]), key=lambda x:x[1])])

for k in range(num_z):
    for j in range(num_phi):
        ind_z[k][j] += num_phi*k

II = []
for k in range(num_z):
    for j in range(num_phi):
        II.append(ind_z[k][j])

phi_sort = [phi_r[i] for i in I]
phi_sort1 = [phi_sort[i] for i in II]
z_sort1 = [z_sort[i] for i in II]

K_sort = [[K[i][j] for i in I] for j in I]
K_sort1 = [[K_sort[i][j] for i in II] for j in II]
```

[Result with Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BxJ0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the task before; I wasn't looking closely enough at the matlab code. The following should work.

```
n = len(phi) # number of rows
comb_mat = [r1 + r2 for r1,r2 in zip(phi,z)]
comb_mat_enum = [(comb_mat[i],i) for i in range(n)]
ind = [tup[1] for tup in sorted(comb_mat_enum)]
K_sort = [[K[ind[i]][ind[j]] for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Example:

```
phi = [
    [95,    27],
    [95,     7],
    [95,     7],
    [95,     7],
    [76,    15],
    [76,    97]]
z = [
    [95,    79],
    [48,    95],
    [48,    65],
    [14,     3],
    [42,    84],
    [91,    93]]
K = [[6*i + j for j in range(6)] for i in range(6)]
fstr = '{0:>5}'

n = len(phi) # number of rows
comb_mat = [r1 + r2 for r1,r2 in zip(phi,z)]
comb_mat_enum = [(comb_mat[i],i) for i in range(n)]
ind = [tup[1] for tup in sorted(comb_mat_enum)]
K_sort = [[K[ind[i]][ind[j]] for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

print('Before:')
for row in K:
    print(*map(fstr.format,row))
print('\nAfter:')
for row in K_sort:
    print(*map(fstr.format,row))
```

The result:

```
Before:
    0     1     2     3     4     5
    6     7     8     9    10    11
   12    13    14    15    16    17
   18    19    20    21    22    23
   24    25    26    27    28    29
   30    31    32    33    34    35

After:
   28    29    27    26    25    24
   34    35    33    32    31    30
   22    23    21    20    19    18
   16    17    15    14    13    12
   10    11     9     8     7     6
    4     5     3     2     1     0
```

---

I'm not familiar with IronPython, but the following works without any imports in Python 3.X.

Applying the usual `sorted` function to a matrix seems to lead to the same behavior as Matlab's `sortrows`. For example, compare the first example from [Matlab's documatation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html) to the following.

```
s = '''\
    95    27    95    79    67    70    69
    95     7    48    95    75     3    31
    95     7    48    65    74    27    95
    95     7    14     3    39     4     3
    76    15    42    84    65     9    43
    76    97    91    93    17    82    38'''

M = []
for line in s.split('\n'):
    M.append(list(map(int,line.split())))
print('Before:')
for row in M:
    print(*row)
print('\nAfter:')
for row in sorted(M):
    print(*row)
```

Resulting output:

```
Before:
95 27 95 79 67 70 69
95 7 48 95 75 3 31
95 7 48 65 74 27 95
95 7 14 3 39 4 3
76 15 42 84 65 9 43
76 97 91 93 17 82 38

After:
76 15 42 84 65 9 43
76 97 91 93 17 82 38
95 7 14 3 39 4 3
95 7 48 65 74 27 95
95 7 48 95 75 3 31
95 27 95 79 67 70 69
```

Modification for ease of reading:

```
fstr = '{0:>5}'
M = []
for line in s.split('\n'):
    M.append(list(map(int,line.split())))
print('Before:')
for row in M:
    print(*map(fstr.format,row))
print('\nAfter:')
for row in sorted(M):
    print(*map(fstr.format,row))
```

Output:

```
Before:
   95    27    95    79    67    70    69
   95     7    48    95    75     3    31
   95     7    48    65    74    27    95
   95     7    14     3    39     4     3
   76    15    42    84    65     9    43
   76    97    91    93    17    82    38

After:
   76    15    42    84    65     9    43
   76    97    91    93    17    82    38
   95     7    14     3    39     4     3
   95     7    48    65    74    27    95
   95     7    48    95    75     3    31
   95    27    95    79    67    70    69
```

Comment: No really. You are sorting only matrix **M** according to its rows. But I need to sort this matrix according to indices of sorted coordinates **phi** and **z**. 
With using of numpy it looks like:
ind = np.lexsort((z, phi))
K_sort = np.zeros(np.shape(K))
for i in range(len(K)):
    for j in range(len(K)):
        K_sort[i][j] = K[ind[i]][ind[j]]

Comment: @SerTet You're right; I wasn't paying close attention to the matlab code. I've edited my answer; I believe that the script at the top should do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Wow, so elegant solution! Thank you!